# How can I use fenced_code_blocks in redcarpet to render the output in block?

Tags: ruby, redcarpet

I use redcarpet and kramdown trying to render the output in a block. It outputs the following result with HTML tags in the UI instead of rendering the output in a block. How can I use redcarpet and kramdown to render the output in an actual block(see the follwing expected output?

PS: My ruby project didn't have any HTML files, the HTML code is handled by another team and I don't have access to modify the HTML code. I produce the output and it will post it to the UI.

````
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, :fenced_code_blocks=> true)
a=markdown.render("```hello```")
puts Kramdown::Document.new(a).to_html
#=> <p><code>Hello</code><p>
````

I would like to see hello wrapped with the rectangle instead of wrapping the hello with tags.Just like in stackoverflow when we use ``` it will wrap the information inside the grey rectangle
expected output:

```
Hello
```

Comment: What are you asking? You are rending a markdown to HTML but you don't want HTML? what do you mean an "actual block"?

Comment: @engineersmnky I added the expected output. Can I do something in ruby allowing the html tags to convert to the actual block(wrapping text with a rectangle)? Just like in stackoverflow when we use ``` it will be wrapping the information inside the grey rectangle.

Comment: This is what that "block" looks like as HTML `<code class="hljs language-ruby">Hello</code>`, (All I did was inspect the source of this page) so it appears that the markdown is doing exactly what is expected. The rest of the styling is just CSS

Comment: @engineersmnky if my above code is correct, I think it may cause by how another handles team my output. I saw my output is passed to one of their function as {"id": "id", "message": "my output". I think it just pass my output as the way it is instead of parsing the html tags.